# unmarshalling XML with multiple namespaces

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

i am already parsing a XML that has a name space.

```
xmlns="http://www.myweb/ns/v1"
```

Now suddenly the client has modified the xml and is sending one more namespace with this.

```
xmlns:mds="http://www.yourweb.com/ns/data"
```

So now i am getting two namespaces

```
xmlns:mds="http://www.yourweb.com/ns/data" xmlns="http://www.myweb/ns/v1"
```

Every thing else is working fine except the newly added fields.
Example is

```
<PortletData mds:Name="Entered" Id="19" DbId="1346">
```

I can not read the attribute `mds:Nam`e.

Now the question is: 
Do I have to generate all of the POJO classes using new XSD or do i can alter the existing code in some way.

I am looking for a different way, as all the old JAVA POJO regarding current XSD is in a Jar File that is used by other applications too.

Kindly guide me with the available options.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The following should help: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thanks Blaise. I am looking into it. Actually before posting it here i already went through that link. Let me try with that link again.

Comment: Id try to generate the classes from your new XSD to a temp location and check for differences to your current code base. I assume there will pop up a new Name.java and your PortletData.java will have an additional public field for said Name-Attribute. Considered other applciations are using "a Jar" id recomend to make sure they dont need to support the new Attribute which in the end is a change of the interface that should lead to generating new classes (e.g. we use Maven to generate any XSD/XML o.ä. defined classes per build)

Comment: Thanks Blaise that was the answer..!! :)